# `Files` application windows launch "under" pycharm?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, launcher

Well since I installed pycharm through snap, the launcher seems to act strange.

Whenever I launch an application from `Files` it shows the pycharm symbol, and all windows are below that symbol. Similar when switch windows through alt-tab/alt-backtick, they are under pycharm.

What caused this, and how do I fix this?

[image: preview]

Comment: @coder_v_3.0 or paul23 , saying "app from files", do you mean non-installed apps (portable, locally compiled, ...) or happen even with installed applications?

Comment: When we launch files, It normally launched. When I open some files from the pycharm 'show in files' option. After all launches from the files also come under the pycharm icon.

Comment: I have installed pycharm professional edition

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the additional drivers. Or get applications from Ubuntu software. For snaps, try installing Multipass . It improves performance of snaps.

Comment: Hope this works :)

Comment: Does it work? I don't think so

Comment: @coder_v_3.0 Could you put a comment under the question, so users trying to help can address you. Also edit the question if you have more details.

Comment: thanks @user.dz I have put comments under question

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -aux | grep pycharm
```

Surprising this will stop the behavior

Comment: Could you explain what this is doing??

Comment: This doesn't really "stop" the behavior per-se.  This in itself does *nothing* to affect PyCharm.